# Useful PowerShell one liners

Tags: .net, powershell, scripting, scripting-language

Provide one line PowerShell script that you found useful, one script per answer please.

There is a similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285064/what-are-some-good-powershell-script-repositories), but this one gives only links to pages with scripts, lets answers one by one here and have a contributed list of most frequently used or most useful scripts.

1. List most recent version of files

   `ls -r -fi *.lis | sort @{expression={$_.Name}}, @{expression={$_.LastWriteTime};Descending=$true} | select Directory, Name, lastwritetime | Group-Object Name | %{$_.Group | Select -first 1}`
2. `gps programThatIsAnnoyingMe | kill`
3. Open a file with its registered program (like `start` e.g `start foo.xls`)

   `ii foo.xls`
4. Retrieves and displays the paths to the system's Special Folder's

   `[enum]::getvalues([system.environment+specialfolder]) | foreach {"$_ maps to " + [system.Environment]::GetFolderPath($_)}`
5. Copy Environment value to clipboard (so now u know how to use clipboard!)

   `$env:appdata | % { [windows.forms.clipboard]::SetText($input) }`

   OR
   `ls | clip`

**With SnapIns**

1. Files between two changeset numbers in TFS

   `Get-TfsItemHistory <location> -Recurse -Version <label1>~<label2> | 
   % { $(Get-TfsChangeset $_.ChangeSetID).Changes } |
   % { $_.Item.ServerItem } | Sort-Object -Unique`
2. Gets queue messages with errors over all Hub servers in exchange 200

   `Get-ExchangeServer | ?{$_.IsHubTransportServer -eq $true} | Get-Queue 
   | ?{$_.LastError -ne $null} | Sort-Object -Descending -Property MessageCount 
   | ft -Property NextHopDomain,@{l="Count";e={$_.MessageCount}},@{l="Last Try";e={$_.LastRetryTime.tosting("M/dd hh:mm")}},@{l="Retry";e={$_.NextRetryTime.tostring("M/dd hh:mm")}},Status,LastError -AutoSize`

Comment: Polls should be Community WIKIs

Comment: And typically don't belong on SO anyway.

Comment: @EBGreen: often no, they don't.  I think this one is pretty good, though (if we clear up the wording some).  It can server as a good PS introduction.

Comment: I agree that this particular poll might fit better tan most. To be honest though, I think a group of one liners would be a terrible introduction to PS. There will be all kinds of aliases and assumed knowledge involved. For instance one of my favorites is "ii." no way that would help a beginner.

Comment: Yuck. Not a question. Stuff like this should go on http://wiki.poshcode.org or something

Comment: Just because you put A LOT of crap on one line does not really make it a one-liner.

Answer (score 21):

At about 6:00 PM....

```
exit
```

Answer (score 13):

Well, here is one I use often along with some explanation.

```
ii .
```

The ii is an alias for Invoke-Item. This commandlet essentially invokes whatever command is registered in windows for the following item. So this:

```
ii foo.xls
```

Would open `foo.xls` in Excel (assuming you have Excel installed and .xls files are associated to Excel).

In `ii .` the `.` refers to the current working directory, so the command would cause windows explorer to open at the current directory.

Comment: You can do that in a normal prompt, just type foo.xls and it will start Excel/OpenOffice/Whatever you have associated.  Type Explorer and it will start a windows explorer session at that location.

Comment: I usually do this using `start .`, `start myFile.xls`, or `start "" "My File.xls"`. How is Invoke-Item superior to the normal start command?

Comment: @Hosam, you use start myfile.xls in powershell?

Comment: @Christian, to be pedantically correct, typing foo.xls will not work, you would have to type .\foo.xls. Also, you are correct that typing Explorer will work, but that is 8 characters compared to the 4 characters of ii .

Comment: Nice! I had created a script that would do the same through the Shell.Application object, but that's a lot simpler!

Comment: @EBGreen: No, I use it in CMD, but wouldn't it work in PowerShell?

Comment: EB, I can fraps it if you like ;)

Comment: @Christian, Please do. Then post to explain how and why you changed this basic functionality of powershell.

Comment: @EBGreen: Then please accept my apology. I used to think that all CMD commands were available in PowerShell. I was clearly wrong.

Comment: There are some aliases to give you essentially the same functionality but not all of the commands are covered. Start in PS is an alias for Start-Process. a .xls file is not an exe so it will fail.

Comment: @EBGreen: start only exists in V2, persionally I created my own function for V1

Answer (score 13):

List all the files that I've updated today:

```
dir | ?{$_.LastWriteTime -ge [DateTime]::Today}
```

Use it so often that I've actually created a little function in my profile:

```
function Where-UpdatedSince{
Param([DateTime]$date = [DateTime]::Today,
      [switch]$before=$False)
Process
{ 
    if (($_.LastWriteTime -ge $date) -xor $before)
    {
        Write-Output $_
    }
} 
};  set-item -path alias:wus -value Where-UpdatedSince
```

So I can say:

```
dir | wus
dir | wus "1/1/2009"
```

To see stuff updated before today:

```
dir | wus -before
```

Comment: It makes better sense to declare `Where-UpdatedSince` as a function. Also `-before` parameter could be `[switch]`.

Comment: @stej - Where-UpdatedSince is a function. I've update the -before parameter to a switch. That wasn't around in PS v1 when I originally wrote this.

Comment: I ment 'filter', not 'function' :) I just added comment to keep it up to date - for anybody comming along and reading your post.

Answer (score 6):

My favorite powershell one liner

```
gps programThatIsAnnoyingMe | kill
```

Answer (score 4):

```
($x=new-object xml).Load("http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot");$x.RDF.item|?{$_.creator-ne"kdawson"}|fl descr*
```

My favorite: It's a slashdot reader sans the horrible submissions by mr. kdawson. It's designed to be fewer than 120 chars which allows it to be used as signature on /.

Answer (score 3):

Retrieves and displays the paths to the system's Special Folder's

```
[enum]::getvalues([system.environment+specialfolder]) | foreach {"$_ maps to " + [system.Environment]::GetFolderPath($_)}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found it useful to show values of environment variables

```
dir env:
```

And you can copy an env value as well to the clipboard

```
$env:appdata | % { [windows.forms.clipboard]::SetText($input) }
```

(you need to have windows.forms loaded before the call:  Add-Type –a system.windows.forms; and run PowerShell with -STA switch)

Answer (score 3):

I don't like complicated applications for counting lines of code, especially because I consider it to be a bogus metric in the first place.  I end up using a PS one-liner instead:

```
PS C:\Path> (dir -include *.cs,*.xaml -recurse | select-string .).Count
```

I just include the extensions of the files I want to include in the line count and go for it from the project's root directory.

Comment: I usually do `(gci -r -inc *.cs,*.xaml|gc)-ne''|measure`

Answer (score 3):

Suppress Visual Studio 2012 ALL CAPS Menus - The very first thing I do after installing VS2012.

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\General -Name SuppressUppercaseConversion -Type DWord -Value 1
```

Thanks to [Richard Banks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/63179/richard-banks) who discovered the registry value.

Answer (score 3):

I hesitate to enumerate my list of PowerShell one-liners one by one as the list numbers just about 400 entries at present! :-) But here are a few of my favorites, to pique your interest:

- List all type accelerators (requires [PSCX](http://pscx.codeplex.com/)): `[accelerators]::get`
- Convert a string representation of XML to actual XML: `[xml]"<root><a>...</a></root>"`
- Dump an object (increase depth for more detail): `$PWD | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 2`
- Recall command from history by substring (looking up earlier 'cd' cmd): `#cd`
- Access C# enum value: `[System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Singleline`
- Generate bar chart (requires Jeff Hicks' [cmdlet](http://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/tag/graphing/)): `ls . | select name,length | Out-ConsoleGraph -prop length -grid`

The whole collection is publicly available in a 4-part series published on Simple-Talk.com -- I hope that these will be useful to SO readers!

- Part 1: [Help, Syntax, Display and Files](http://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/powershell/powershell-one-liners-help,-syntax,-display-and--files/)
- Part 2: [Variables, Parameters, Properties, and Objects](http://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/powershell/powershell-one-liners-variables,-parameters,-properties,-and-objects/)
- Part 3: [Collections and Hash Tables](http://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/powershell/powershell-one-liners--collections,-hashtables,-arrays-and-strings/)
- Part 4: [Files and Data Streams](http://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/powershell/powershell-one-liners--accessing,-handling-and-writing-data-/)

I wanted to call the series *"Do Anything in One Line of PowerShell"* but my editor wanted something more terse, so we went with *PowerShell One-Liners*. Though in the interests of full disclosure, only 98% or so are really one-liners in the true spirit of the term; I thought that was close enough with rounding... :-)

Comment: Awesome article @Michael, it is a one stop reference for everything PowerShell!

Answer (score 2):

This shows which processes are using which versions of the MS CRT DLLs:

```
gps | select ProcessName -exp Modules -ea 0 | 
  where {$_.modulename -match 'msvc'} | sort ModuleName | 
  Format-Table ProcessName -GroupBy ModuleName
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be cheating since I have the TFS PowerTools snap installed but this is quite useful for finding out which files have changed between two changesets, versions, or labels.

```
Get-TfsItemHistory <location> -Recurse -Version <label1>~<label2> | 
% { $(Get-TfsChangeset $_.ChangeSetID).Changes } |
% { $_.Item.ServerItem } | Sort-Object -Unique
```

Answer (score 1):

List all Windows Providers in alpha order:

```
get-winevent -listprovider microsoft-windows* | % {$_.Name} | sort
```

Actually you can use this with a wildcard for any specific group of Providers:

```
get-winevent -listprovider microsoft-windows-Securit* | % {$_.Name} | sort
```

Answer (score 1):

pipe the output of something to the clipboard

```
ls | clip
```

Answer (score 1):

Generate some pseudo random bytes in a file.

```
[Byte[]]$out=@(); 0..9 | %{$out += Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 255}; [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("random",$out)
```

The Get-Random algorithm takes a seed from the system clock, so don't use this for serious cryptographic needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
cls
```

Get rid of all the intractable, -verbose red marks after each of my attempted commands, letting me resume with a nice posh clear looking screen.

Answer (score 0):

Gets queue messages with errors over all Hub servers in exchange 2007 (with some formatting)

```
Get-ExchangeServer | ?{$_.IsHubTransportServer -eq $true} | Get-Queue | ?{$_.LastError -ne $null} | Sort-Object -Descending -Property MessageCount | ft -Property NextHopDomain,@{l="Count";e={$_.MessageCount}},@{l="Last Try";e={$_.LastRetryTime.tosting("M/dd hh:mm")}},@{l="Retry";e={$_.NextRetryTime.tostring("M/dd hh:mm")}},Status,LastError -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 0):

Function display's System Uptime 
I use this for my accounting spreadsheet

```
    function get-uptime
{
$PCounter = "System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter"
$counter = new-object $PCounter System,"System Up Time"
$value = $counter.NextValue()
$uptime = [System.TimeSpan]::FromSeconds($counter.NextValue())
"Uptime: $uptime"
"System Boot: " + ((get-date) - $uptime)
}
```

Comment: In V2 there is easier way how to read performance counters: `Get-Counter System,"System Up Time"`.

Answer (score 0):

Copy some to the desktop:

```
Copy-Item $home\*.txt ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop"))
```